# Bigquery query to get all occurences that match a certain pattern after slash

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery that has a column with many rows that contain strings that can be something like this

```
row 1 mmmmm hhhhh ccccc tttt /tst /kl:2 /aaaa  nnnn
row 2 ddd bb /lamp /mode:2 /nana
row 3 /dada
```

I need to catch all of the:
tst, kl and aaaa, lamp, mode, nana, dada (meaning all of the words after slash)

How do i do that?

Tried something like this but it did not find

```
SELECT column1,
  SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(column1,r'(\/.*?(\s|$))', ','))  AS regex_found  
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use query similar to this one. It returns single repeated columns `tokens` containing words that you're interested in:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(column, r'\/([^ :]+)') AS tokens
FROM
  UNNEST(['mmmmm hhhhh ccccc tttt /tst /kl:2 /aaaa  nnnn', 'ddd bb /lamp /mode:2 /nana', '/dada']) AS column
```

Comment: Additional to what Marcin has said, if you would like to know more about the used functions, take a look at the docs for [_Regexp Extract All_](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) and [_Unnest_](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays)